# How to move a zip file to a folder

Tags: python, zip

I have a large no. of zip file whose name is only numerical. Now each zip file contains a folder having the same name as the zip file( ie if the name of the zip file is say 1234.zip then the name of the folder will also be 1234). Also this folder contains a text file say atextfile.txt, which contains  integer specifying the year of the zip say 2016.
Now I want to move each zip file to its respective folder ie year wise. Meaning what i want to do is extract the value of year ie 2016 and make a folder named 2016, move the zip file to this folder and do the same for the next zip file.
I was successful in retrieving the year and storing it in a variable named year.
The  code I have written so far:

```
    import glob
    import os
    import zipfile
    import shutil
    for zip_name in glob.glob('[0-9]*.zip'):
        z=zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name)
        # To remove '.zip' from the name of zip_name
        subdir = zip_name[:-4]
        with z.open('{}/atextfile.txt'.format(subdir)) as f:
            for line in f:
                for word in line:
                    year = word
                    # the file atextfile.txt has many lines containing many                        integer of which the first line represents the year.
                    break
                else:
                    continue
                break
        z.close()
        if not os.path.exists(year):
            os.makedirs(year)
        shutil.move(zip_name, year)
```

This is gives the error:
 WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
 I googled it and I came to know that the reason behind this is because my zip file is already opened. But I am unable to solve this problem, so please help.
UPDATE: The problem is solved I stored the zip_name and year in a text file and then in another program read the text file and moved the corresponding zip file to its year folder. Thanks for responses.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have the folder open. Look at your active programs. Do you have the folder open?

Answer (score 0):

> Try with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and ROBOCOPY:

```
import glob
import os
import zipfile
import subprocess

for zip_name in glob.glob('[0-9]*.zip'):
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name)
    # To remove '.zip' from the name of zip_name
    subdir = zip_name[:-4]
    with z.open('{}/atextfile.txt'.format(subdir)) as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line:
                year = word
                break
            else:
                continue
            break
    z.close()
    if not os.path.exists(year):
        os.makedirs(year)
    command = 'ROBOCOPY {} {} /S /MOVE'.format(zip_name, year)
    subprocess.call(command)
```

Comment: It is showing the error: ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory E:\Meta_files\1.zip\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, there seemed to be a problem with the way you were getting the year.

```
import glob
import os
import zipfile
import shutil

for zip_name in glob.glob('[0-9]*.zip'):
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name)
    subdir = os.path.splitext(zip_name)[0]

    with z.open('{}/atextfile.txt'.format(subdir)) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.lower().startswith("date"):
                year = line.split('-')[-1]
                break

    if not os.path.exists(year):
        os.makedirs(year)

    z.close()
    shutil.move(zip_name, year)
```

Also, it is better to use the [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext) function to extract your `zip_name`

Comment: I tried it but its still not working. The format of data in file is a little different. It contains many line with each line looking like this: attribute = value ex. Date = 23-JUL-2013. So I have to extract the year 2013 first using : for word in line.split('=') and then in some cases it was like this : Date=23-JUL-2013, so i had to write : word = word.strip(). And then i had to find the word Date and then proceed to store the whole date in a variable such as variable has value 23-JUL-2013 and then to extract the year I wrote year = variable[:-4]. Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Is your code creating the correct folders? i.e. if you comment out the `shutil.move()` does it create everything?

Comment: I have updated the script to work with your file format.

Comment: Can you check to see if you have any files in the folder with the same name as the year that would be created as a folder? I suggest you add `print year` just before the move statement so you can see which entry it is failing on.

Comment: The year for each zip file is getting printed correctly and the creation of respective folder is also happening accordingly, the problem is with the moving of zip file to the folder created. It always shows error stating that the zip file is currently in use. Also when I open the directory there is the folder with the year as its name and inside it is the first zip file of the directory, while the same zip file is also present in the directory.

Comment: The error can occur if files or folders are already present. Try starting with an empty structure and just the zip files.

Comment: I always do that, every time i run my program start with a directory with only zip files.